# BitBucket Merge conflict edit on one check-in and deleted file on other check-in

Tags: bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I am at a client which is the first time using bitbucket and I only really know DevOps.

The Bitbucket users that know this well have quit and the two people that created the merge conflict are gone

I have a deleted File and an edit of that same file that is conflicting.  I would love to resolve the conflict on either side I don't actually care.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mark

[image]